# Call method on ALL objects conforming to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift

### Update

As [maddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) mentioned bellow in the comments it's obvious you need a reference to an object to be able to call a method on it. That is probably in fact my question: how do you keep track of all objects that implement a protocol?

Looking back at Objective-C I thought about using something similar to `+load` or `+initialize` methods and add the object as an observer for a specific `NSNotification`. But that wouldn't work since those methods are class methods and not instance methods.

So, trying to be even a little bit more specific: is there a method that get's called on all objects after they are created? A method that would allow me to add that object to a collection that I manage or as an observer for a specific `NSNotification`?

P.S: I haven't tried adding to much details to the problem 'cause I didn't want to "polute" you with my bad, non-sense ideas.

### Original

So... Imagine this piece of code:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {

    func myMethod()

}

public class MyClass: MyProtocol {

    func myMethod() {
        print("myMethod called on MyClass")
    }    

}

extension UIView: MyProtocol {

    func myMethod() {
        print("myMethod called on UIView")
    }

}

let myObject = MyClass()
let myView = UIView()
```

Now... I'm trying to figure out a way to call `myMethod` on both these objects from a 3rd one which is not aware of them - here's a simplified example of the 3rd one:

```
class MyManager {

    func callMyMethodOnAllObjecs() {
        // Do something here so that ALL objects present in memory that conform to MyProtocol get their myMethod called
    }        

}
```

Anyone?

Comment: Without knowing *what* exists? What is "they" in your question? Please update your question to be clearer.

Comment: What you are asking makes no sense. You need a reference to an object to be able to call a method on it.

Comment: Why don't you update your question to clearly describe what you are really trying to accomplish. Right now it seems you are asking about the wrong solution to a problem. Ask about the original problem instead of this possible solution.

Comment: Well what I asked is what I want to achieve (if possible). I have a protocol which adds a method to any object that conforms to that protocol. When my `MyManager` properties change I want all my objects conforming to that protocol to be made aware of that and react independently.

Comment: There is no Swift equivalent for `+load`, and no mechanism to find all objects (with a certain property). Something like this was discussed on the swift-evolution mailing list, starting at https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20161114/028914.html.

Comment: You definitely need to use the Objc  runtime for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A heads up that what you need requires features belonging to dynamically typed languages, this means using the Objective-C runtime. This doesn't pose many technical challenges, but restricts the area of Swift entities you can use - basically only `NSObject` derived classes.

Briefly, here's what you need:

1. support in `MyManager` for registering newly created objects
2. a piece of code that needs to be executed by all `MyProtocol` instances that register themselves to `MyManager`
3. most important, code that doesn't generate memory leaks, as registering an object within `MyManager` poses the risk of having the manager indefinitely retain that object.

Below you can find a code that solves the problem:

```
// Since we need ObjectiveC specific runtime features, we need to
// restrict the protocol to the NSObject protocol
protocol MyProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    func myMethod()
}

public class MyClass: NSObject, MyProtocol {
    func myMethod() {
        print("myMethod called on MyClass")
    }
    
}

extension UIView: MyProtocol {
    
    func myMethod() {
        print("myMethod called on UIView")
    }   
}

extension NSObject {
    // this is an alternative to the original init method, that besides the
    // original edit it registers the object within MyManager
    @objc func swizzledInit() -> NSObject {
        // this is not recursive, as init() in exchanged with swizzledInit()
        let `self` = swizzledInit()
        if let `self` = self as? MyProtocol {
            // the object is MyProtocol
            MyManager.shared.register(self)
        }
        return self
    }
}

class MyManager {
    
    static let shared = MyManager()
    private var objecters = [() -> MyProtocol?]()
    
    private init() {
        // let's swizzle init() with our custom init
        if let m1 = class_getInstanceMethod(NSObject.self, #selector(NSObject.init)),
           let m2 = class_getInstanceMethod(NSObject.self, #selector(NSObject.swizzledInit)) {
            method_exchangeImplementations(m1, m2)
        }
    }
    
    public func register(_ object: MyProtocol) {
        // registering a block in order to be able to keep a weak reference to
        // the registered object
        objecters.append({ [weak object] in return object })
    }
    
    
    func callMyMethodOnAllObjecs() {
        var newList =  [() -> MyProtocol?]()
        // go through the list of registered blocks, execute the method,
        // and retain only the ones for wich the object is still alive
        for object in objecters {
            if let o = object() {
                newList.append(object)
                o.myMethod()
            }
        }
        objecters = newList
    }
    
}

// This is to make sure the manager is instantiated first,
// and thus it swizzles the NSObject initializer
_ = MyManager.shared

let myObject = MyClass()
let myView = UIView()

// an instance of MyClass and one of UIView will print stuff
MyManager.shared.callMyMethodOnAllObjecs()
```

In summary, the above code:

1. swizzles the `init` of `NSObject` so that besides the original `init` it also registers the object to your manager.
2. keeps a list of closure that return objects instead of the object themselves, in order to be able to weakly reference those objects, thus to avoid keeping the objects alive more than they should be
3. cleans up the closures whose objects got deallocated when `callMyMethodOnAllObjecs` is invoked.

Comment: This! :) Thanks man ;) My targeted objects are all, or at least 99.9% of them, subclasses of NSObject (UIView, UIViewControllers, etc. - basically anything related to an app's UI) so that limitation shouldn't be a big problem for me. I've got to check how the memory management works in this case. But other then that this is what I want. Awesome!

Comment: @MihaiFratu there there should be no memory leaks with the code above, as the closure that captures the registered object keeps a weak references to the object, thus the objects will get deallocated when needed, just like the reference would not be there.

Comment: Another big thumbs up for that. That's just... Smart! :) Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could have your `MyProtocol` objects listen for a notification from `NotificationCenter`, and make `myMethod()` be the method that is fired when a notification is received.

Then all objects that currently exist and adhere to that protocol will fire the method whenever you post the notification to `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: Well that's what I thought to do. But then I got stuck finding a good way to add the objects as observers for said notification. Any idea?

Comment: you could place the code to listen for notifications in a custom init method for your objects

Comment: But that would mean that a simple extension for classes such as `UIView` wouldn't work since my custom init would not be called when, say, a view is instantiated via a Storyboard.

Comment: Yeah if you have needs like that, I would consider putting a "listenForNotification" method with a default implementation as part of your protocol, then calling that method in custom inits when and where you can, or just calling it after you instantiate an object when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean if you don't know if the method exists on the object.  If so, just run the test on the method before calling it:

```
myObject.respondsToSelector(Selector("myMethod")) // true if it can respond to it
```

----- updated answer to updated question:

```
if(myObject && myObject.respondsToSelector(Selector("myMethod")))  
    [myMutableDic setObject:myObject forKey:@"myObject"];

if(myView && myView.respondsToSelector(Selector("myMethod")))
    [myMutableDic setObject:myView forKey:@"myView"];

// and call all myMethods on this set ------------------------------ 
for (id key in [myMutableDic allKeys]) {
    id obj = [myMutableDic objectForKey:key];
    [obj myMethod]; // since already checked before putting it into dictionary
}

// or use the block enumeration - does the same thing: 
[myMutableDic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    [obj myMethod];
}];

// ps didn't test it may need to fix grammar
```

Comment: See my updated question. Because my objects conform to the protocol I know that the method is implemented. My problem is that I want to call that method on **all** objects available in memory at a given time and I don't have a way to know which those objects are.

Answer (score 0):

this way you can have add or remove observer methods ready to use. also you can create custom init  to call this methods when instance is created.

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {

    func myMethod()
    func addObserverForMyMethod()
    func removeMyMethodObserver()


}

extension MyProtocol {
    func addObserverForMyMethod() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.myMethod), name: Notification.Name("myMethodCall"), object: nil)
    }
    func removeMyMethodObserver() {
        NSNotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: "myMethodCall", object: nil)
    }
}

public class MyClass: MyProtocol {

    func myMethod() {
        print("myMethod called on MyClass")
    }    

}

extension UIView: MyProtocol {

    func myMethod() {
        print("myMethod called on UIView")
    }

}

let myObject = MyClass()
let myView = UIView()
myObject.addObserverForMyMethod()
myView.addObserverForMyMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no overridable initialize method called on all objects. In fact, in swift there is nothing inherited by base classes at all unless they inherit from `NSObject`. This type of dynamism purposefully doesn't exist in swift. In order to do something like this, I'd recommend that you use the objective C runtime. Consider using Injection for Xcode's source as a jumping off point: https://github.com/johnno1962/injectionforxcode/blob/master/InjectionPluginLite/Classes/BundleSweeper.h

but really this goes very strongly against the grain in swift. If you're willing to consider something similar, this might work for you, and at the same time be more type safe (and it has the benefit of allowing heterogeneous swift types):

```
protocol X {
    static var insts:[X]{ get }
    static func create() -> X
}

final class A:X{
     static func create() -> X {
        let it = A()
        insts.append(it)
        return it
    }

    static var insts:[X] = []

}
struct B:X{
    static func create() -> X {
        let it = B()
        insts.append(it)
        return it
    }

    static var insts:[X] = []

}

var protocols:[X.Type] = [A.self, B.self]
for p in protocols {
    p.insts.forEach({print($0)})
}
```